# Get the latest 3 nodes foreach taxonomy term in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

I am trying to setup a query to get the 3 most recent nodes (nid) foreach taxonomy term (tid).  Is this possible to set up on one query?

Here are how my tables are set up (not displaying full table info)

**taxonomy_index** (Holds the taxonomy ids that are associated to a node)

```
nid      tid
1         20
1         21
1         22
2         20
2         21
3         23
3         24
4         20
4         21
5         20
5         21
5         22
5         23
6         20
6         21
6         24
7         20
7         21
8         20
8         21
9         20
9         21
9         22
9         23
.....
```

**node** (node information)

```
nid    title           created
1      Article One     1105350260
2      Article Two     1105350259
3      Article Three   1105350261
4      Article Four    1105350280
5      Article Five    1105350290
6      Article Six     1105350290
.....
```

I'm envisioning a result like this if I wanted to see the latest 3 nodes for tids: 20, 21, 22:

```
tid     nid
20       1
20       2
20       4
21       1
21       2
21       4
22       1
22       5
22       9
```

Is this possible in one query?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @sgeddes I am using Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can try follwing query:-

```
SELECT t.tid, t.nid
FROM taxonomy_index s
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM taxonomy_index f
      WHERE f.tid = s.tid
  AND f.nid <= s.nid    
  ) <= 3;
```

here i have used <=3 #cond, in case if any tid dont have 3 records the it will fetch 2 or 1, whichever is more.

Comment: In this query you are not taking creation timestamp into account

Comment: Because, that is not required in final result.